# Why atomic.Load not called to load gcphase in runtime.GC?

Tags: go, runtime

I wonder why `gcphase` is not protected with `atomic.Load`:

```
n := atomic.Load(&work.cycles)
if gcphase == _GCmark {
    // Wait until sweep termination, mark, and mark
    // termination of cycle N complete.
    gp.schedlink = work.sweepWaiters.head
    work.sweepWaiters.head.set(gp)
    goparkunlock(&work.sweepWaiters.lock, "wait for GC cycle", traceEvGoBlock, 1)
} else {
    // We're in sweep N already.
    unlock(&work.sweepWaiters.lock)
}
```

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

Code excerpt:

```
func setGCPhase(x uint32) {
    atomic.Store(&gcphase, x)
    writeBarrier.needed = gcphase == _GCmark || gcphase == _GCmarktermination
    writeBarrier.enabled = writeBarrier.needed || writeBarrier.cgo
}
```

while `gcphase` is a global variable, but all writes to `gcphase` are done through the above function.

There were several variables in runtime which aren't paired properly, but seems they have reason for it and were sure they were having the exclusive access to it.

> Here is the issue https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21931 filed about the same and here https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/65210 GC developers had some discussions on changing the same.